# "Waiting for message" label in the keyboard when waiting for an OTP

Tags: android

I have an app that uses OTP codes for authentication. OTP codes are sent by email.

When the users are in the screen to enter the OTP code, some of them can see a loading indicator over the keyboard with the label "waiting for message".

This is something not added by us, and also this never gets completed, as the OTP comes to email inbox. As users see this message in the keyboard, they keep waiting for a real OTP message to appear there and, as this never happens, they complaint about OTP code not working.

To improve the UX... is there anyway to avoid that label/loading/message to appear automatically in the keyboard?

[image]